# Where do docker images get pulled from when I log into a different image repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecr

I'm trying to set up some infrastructure using AWS ECR to store docker images. I'm just wondering if I have access to the same base images that I do in the docker hub. E.G. `FROM node` works in my Dockerfile after I log in to ECR. I'm just wondering where this image is getting pulled from. I can't find anything regarding a public ECR repository that stores base images. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of a Docker image identifies the repository that it comes from. For example:

`docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazonlinux:latest`

The registry is `aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`, the image name is `amazonlinux`, and the version is `latest`. The punctuation characters `/` and `:` separate these three components.

When you pull from Docker hub, you don't have a registry name, just an image name and version (`node:latest`).

When you run `docker login`, it *adds* credentials to those known by Docker. You can login to as many registries as you want. When you then run `docker pull`, it looks to see if it has credentials for the specific registry.